# Remove an app from Notification Center preference pane

Tags: system-settings, facebook, notifications

My girlfriend added Facebook to my Notification Center. I tried to set the alert style to none, and you can see the check mark to show items in Notification Center is deselected.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRaKV.png]

I want it completely gone but don't know how else to configure things.

Comment: Have you tried signing out / deleting Facebook from the Mail, Contacts, Calendars system preference pane? Just select Facebook on the left and press - to delete the feed. After a reboot, you might try adding Facebook again and see if it's not sending notifications, but you might have to choose to remove that account if there is a bug in the controls. You're doing the correct steps in Notification center controls AFAIK.

Comment: Same problem with the Hazel application.  I've deleted the application, but it's still listed in the Notifications preferences!  Very irritating.

Comment: A very similar question on Stack Overflow, with some answers: [Remove application from Notification Center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11993145/578288).

Comment: (Despite the similarity, I don’t suggest merging this question with the Stack Overflow one. The asker of that question *wrote* the app that they want to remove from the Notification Center, so answers that involve editing the app are valid there but not here.)

Answer (score 32):

Open Safari › Preferences › Notifications
There you can remove objects permanently by selecting the notification you wish to delete and then either hitting the **delete key** or by using the remove button ('-') if it exists.

Comment: Not possible in Sierra, not listed there

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that worked. All the other searches for removing notification app were showing useless stuff, like deleting the  NotificationCenter .db file or setting alert style to 'None'.

Comment: This was driving me crazy!  This solution worked for me too on Big Sur. Only thing to note is that the path to this is Open Safari › Preferences › Websites > Notifications then select the website name on the right and click the "Remove" button bottom left. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Highlight the desired app and hit <kbd>delete</kbd>

Comment: This is *the* answer! Note: **delete**, not  **backspace**, as the latter does not work. This is strange, Apple! Tested on High Sierra…

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. Go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts . You can remove Facebook account from there and then it will no longer appear in the notification center at all

Answer (score 2):

Go to Mail, Contact & Calendars and click on minus sign (-) after selecting Facebook on the left pane.

Comment: Actually I did that before asking the question. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove these using Safari → Preferences → Websites → Notifications -> (Select the websites you wish to remove) → Remove.

While you are there, also consider unchecking **Allow websites to ask for permission to send push notifications**.

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer found here that worked for me with an app I had uninstalled but was still in the notification center: [MacRumors Forums: Remove app from "In Notification Center" list](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/remove-app-from-in-notification-center-list.1425365/)

In that forum thread, two users discover that there exists a folder `/Users/<your-username>/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter/`. That folder contains a database file.

Comment: There's no answer on that forum.

Comment: The linked forum thread indeed doesn’t give a solution, but at least the `NotificationCenter` folder it mentions is relevant. There are solutions that involve editing the database in that folder: see the answers to [“Remove application from Notification Center” – Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993145/remove-application-from-notification-center).

Answer (score 1):

For websites that added a Notification, you can remove it by going to Safari Preferences, to the "Websites" tab, then to the "Notifications" section.  When you remove it from there, it automatically disappears from the Notifications prefpane.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag it down to Not in Notification Center list.

Comment: The App is already in the Not in Notification Center list.

Comment: Although technically wrong, I'm glad Bob tried to help because this answer helped me with a similar issue.

Answer (score -2):

Finder -> Go to floder -> ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ -> Delete the plist file related to notification -> Done.

Comment: Can you say which file specifically should be deleted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993145/remove-application-from-notification-center