# As for macOS Notifications in System Preferences, can I restore the app which I deleted?

Tags: macos, notifications

I delete some apps in this window, and I cannot restore them even with the settings them apps.
Is there no way to restore these apps?
This looks that `Not In Notification Center` in this link is gone.
[Remove an app from Notification Center preference pane](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84075/remove-an-app-from-notification-center-preference-pane)

[image]

I think this is similar to the bug of the iOS in which if I select Don't Allow to send the notification when the app is installed, I couldn't modify the notification settings because the app did not exist in the list of notification settings.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7061805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me!!
But I think that there is no `Not In Notification Center` is a bug, so I will post in the Apple's bug tracker system.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784565/7824640